# LoadRunner: Error in iteration, exit Vuser and restart Vuser

Tags: citrix, loadrunner

I have a Citrix LoadRunner test that fails periodically because of bitmap sync issues.  I would like to fail the iteration during these failures and restart the Vuser.  I currently have the login and logout steps in the vuser_init and vuser_end sections so I don't keep logging in and out during the test.  Is ther a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Move the code for your login and logout to independent functions, such as "My_App_Login()" and "My_App_Logout()"   Call these functions from your init and end.    Then, if you need to exit abrubtly for whatever reason, set a semaphore as a file for your virtual user, call your logout function and then issue a return 1, which iterates immediately.   At the beginning of your action check for your semaphore and it it exists then re-login by calling your login

Comment: I assume when you say semaphore you mean a variable. I thought about doing this but I am not catching all errors.  How can I execute a function on any error?  I'm using citrix and am getting alot of ctrx_bitmap_sync errors.  I don't want to have to do a lr_continue_on_error and handle each error.  Is there a way to execute a function for all errors?

Comment: "set a semaphore as a file for your virtual user"   If file exists then you need to (1) Delete semaphore (2) Login

Comment: I have added the logic above but the code doesn't iterate on calling return 1.  I don't have continue on error set because I don't want to try to trap every error.  My current code goes to the vuser_end code and I try to do a return 1 there without success.  How do I call a function on error without trying to trap the error in every place?

Comment: Return 1 will only work if you have it in the Action section which is iterated.  Placing it in the vuser_end() will have no effect on causing an iteration to occur.